# Can not set android clang compilers for Qt Android on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, android-ndk, clang

I installed `Qt Android 5.15.2` on `Ubuntu` but there is problem with the compilers. This is what I have set:

[image]

And here is what QtCreator detects as compilers:

[image]

The first error is displayed here in the Qt version tab:

[image]

and also in the Kit tab I see this errors no matter which compilers I set from the available:

[image]

Why I got this errors? Can please someone that has android kit on Ubuntu already set, tell me which compilers is using and which paths are for the compilers?
I will add more information for the current compilers or kits if needed.

Comment: Off topic but you forgot to mask your username in the first picture. I think it's harmless but if that was your intention you might consider editing the question.

Comment: ah yes, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a x86 compiler for Android. You need to install the specific compiler from the Android SDK/NDK. So the good news is that you might be only missing one step (step 2 below)

I tried to install from the Ubuntu stock packages. That was impossible to get to work.

I was able to set it up in the following way:

1. Download the Qt online installer. Login and DO NOT choose individual packages, install Qt for desktop and Qt for mobile (check the last 3 options). This will install Qt 6 + QtCreator
2. Run QtCreator after everything finishes (+1.2Gb download). Go to Tools>Options>Devices>Android. Check that Java SDK is ok. On the Android section, choose "Set up Android". Accept all licenses.

This is what you should see in the end:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation, the problem was that NDK was not installed correctly and some files were missing. After downloading it again the compilers were auto-detected.